# Convert String from web server to byte array with ESP8266/8285

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I want to store WiFi-credentials and some other configurations on the flash/EEPROM of my ESP8285.

I will receive Strings from an webserver input field. I wrote a little test code to figure out if the storing and converting works. Turns out it doesn't. I cant figure out how to convert a char array to a byte array and neglecting some characters like the ":" when I want to store a MAC-address. Storing SSID, passphrase and channel works well but MAC-address not.

Here is my code snippet when writing to the EEPROM:

```
void writeCredentials() {
  String newSSID = "WRT";
  String newPass = "45568798789098794879784";
  String newBSSID = "3A:79:16:A8:B5:76";
  char buff[sizeof(settings.eeBSSID)];
  byte mac[6];
  char chBuff[3];
  char *ptr;
  newBSSID.toCharArray(buff, newBSSID.length() + 1);
  Serial.println(buff);
  ptr = strtok(buff, ":");
  int index = 0;
  while (ptr != NULL) {
    strcpy(chBuff, ptr);
    Serial.print(" Mac: ");
    Serial.print(chBuff);
    sscanf(&chBuff[2], "%02xd", &mac[index]); //no idea here maybe completely wrong
    index++;
    ptr = strtok(NULL, ":");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  newSSID.toCharArray(settings.eeSSID, newSSID.length() + 1);
  newPass.toCharArray(settings.eePass, newPass.length() + 1);
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(mac); i++) {
    Serial.println(char(mac[i]));
  }
  settings.eeChannel = 12345;
  memcpy(settings.eeBSSID, mac, sizeof(mac));
  EEPROM.put(0, settings);
  Serial.println("Settings saved!");
}
```

For testing purposes I throw the Strings into the writeCredentials() function. Later they will come from an webserver text input form. Everything is managed in a config struct like this:

```
typedef struct WiFi_Settings {
  char eeSSID[32];
  char eePass[32];
  byte eeBSSID[6];
  int eeChannel;
};

WiFi_Settings settings {
  "",
  "",
  {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
  1
};
```

Im struggling for hours to get the newBSSID converted to a byte/uint8_t array which I can store in my struct and which will be later used for the WiFi.begin function of the ESP...

Tested lots of variations with strtok, sscanf and tried to split the char array (stored in buff) into bits of 2 char pieces which I then can convert to an byte and passing it to the byte array but every time something does not work. Maybe somebody can help me?

Comment: `buff` needs to be `newBSSID.length() + 1` bytes long but you make it `sizeof(settings.eeBSSID)` (i.e. 6 bytes)

Comment: Also the usage of `sscanf` is wrong. It should be `sscanf(chBuff, "%02xd", &mac[index]);`

Comment: Or you could just do: `sscanf(buff, "%02xhhd:%02xhhd:%02xhhd:%02xhhd:%02xhhd:%02xhhd", &mac[0], &mac[1], &mac[2], &mac[3], &mac[4], &mac[5]);`

Comment: Using `sscanf(chBuff, "%02xd", &mac[index]);` will crash my ESP immediately. When I changing the index with a static interger, like 0 it works. Whats the error in my code? Using `sscanf(buff, "%02xhhd:%02xhhd:%02xhhd:%02xhhd:%02xhhd:%02xhhd", &mac[0], &mac[1], &mac[2], &mac[3], &mac[4], &mac[5]);` only stores the first byte. See my updated code in my answer.

Comment: Actually `sscanf(chBuff, "%02xd", &mac[index])` is wrong but could not edit my comment because I had already added another comment. The correct is: `sscanf(chBuff, "%02xhhd", &mac[index])`. The reason is that the former expects `&mac[index]` to point to an `int` whereas the latter expects a pointer to `unsigned char`

Comment: Sadly your "correct" version also crashes the ESP... I can't wrap my head around this. Can't be that complicated...

Comment: Please see my other comment. I had the format specifiers mixed up, again! The correct is `%02hhx`, BUT this may not work either. In embedded platforms `sscanf` implementation may be partial. You have to check with Espressif SDK.

Comment: I tried it with `%02hhx` - does not work. Do you see any other possibility to get what I want. Maybe without sscanf?

Comment: Well I just updated the library with the arduino boards manager and now it works with the `%02hhx` style. Unbelievably it was just from version 2.6.2 to 2.6.3. Thank you. Edit: Just looked into the change log. Unbelievable "Add hh (byte) format for printf and scanf (#6896)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified the code just to cover the mac-address problem.

```
typedef struct WiFi_Settings {
  byte eeBSSID[6];
};

WiFi_Settings settings {
  {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
};

void writeCredentials() {
  String newBSSID = "3A:79:16:A8:B5:76";
  char buff[18];
  newBSSID.toCharArray(buff, newBSSID.length() + 1);
  sscanf(buff, "%02xhhd:%02xhhd:%02xhhd:%02xhhd:%02xhhd:%02xhhd", &settings.eeBSSID[0], &settings.eeBSSID[1], &settings.eeBSSID[2], &settings.eeBSSID[3], &settings.eeBSSID[4], &settings.eeBSSID[5]);
  EEPROM.put(0, settings);
  Serial.println("Settings saved!");
  Serial.print("Saved MAC: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(settings.eeBSSID); i++) {
    Serial.print(settings.eeBSSID[i]);
    if (i < 5)  Serial.print(":");
  }
  Serial.println("");
}
```

I tried the solution  P. Kouvarakis mentioned. Sadly it doesn't work fully. Serial output:

```
Settings saved!
Saved MAC: 58:0:0:0:0:0
```

So the first byte is right. The rest wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately I was wrong about the format string it should be: `sscanf(buff, "%02hhx:%02hhx:%02hhx:%02hhx:%02hhx:%02hhx",...`.

Comment: Unfortunately this also doesn't work for me... Serial output is: `Settings saved!
Saved MAC: 3:0:0:0:0:0`

Comment: Well this works on Std C++. See here: https://code.sololearn.com/cSx0p82Ij1hp/#

Comment: See my comment on the main thread. They fixed it in the last version. LoL.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to store the new SSID and password from the webserver. I've made a big project last year and created a WiFi Manager myself.I just found the librarie I created and here is how I do to upload the new SSID and pwd to the EEPROM. I hope this helps in your problem.

```
.
.
.
//New_ssid and New_pass were declared has String
if(New_Input == true){
        int  i=0;
        char *SNew_ssid = &New_ssid[0u];  //Convert String to char 
        char *SNew_pass = &New_pass[0u];
        Serial.print("Trying to connect to: ");
        Serial.println(New_ssid);
        WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA);    //AP e station
        WiFi.begin(SNew_ssid,SNew_pass);   //Connecting to new WiFi
        while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED && i<100){
            delay(200);
            Serial.print(".");
            i++;
        }
        if(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED){  //Connected to new WiFi
            Serial.println("");
            //cleaning EEPROM
            if(New_ssid.length() > 0 && New_pass.length() > 0){
                Serial.println("Cleaning EEPROM...");
                for(i = 0;i < 96;i++){
                    EEPROM.write(i,0);
                }
            }
            //Writing to EEPROM
            Serial.println("Writing SSID to EEPROM...");
            for(i = 0;i < New_ssid.length(); i++){
                EEPROM.write(i,New_ssid[i]);

            }
            Serial.println("Writing Password to EEPROM...");
            for(i = 0;i < New_pass.length(); i++){
                EEPROM.write(32+i,New_pass[i]);
            }
            EEPROM.commit();
.
.
.
```

Here is how get the data from EEPROM don't know if it helps you or not. This part of the code is not the WiFiManager librarie but the main code.

```
.
.
.
Str_Buffer = "Reading SSID and PASSWORD from EEPROM...";
    SendToPrinter(0,"aa",0);
    eSSID = "\0";
    for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++){
        eSSID += char(EEPROM.read(i));
        //Str_Buffer = char(EEPROM.read(i));
    }
    for(int i = 32; i < 96; i++){
        ePASS += char(EEPROM.read(i));
    }


    //Ligação à rede Wifi
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA); //Modo station
    if(eSSID.length() > 1){  //If got any SSID stored at EEPROM
            WiFi.begin(eSSID.c_str(),ePASS.c_str());
            Str_Buffer = "Connecting to: ";
            Str_Buffer += eSSID.c_str();
            SendToPrinter(0,"aa",0);
        }else{
        WiFi.begin(ssid,pass);
        Str_Buffer = "Connecting to: "; //Rede xhockware como definição
        Str_Buffer += ssid;
        SendToPrinter(0,"aa",0);
    }
    int i = 0;

    //Checking Wi-Fi status
    while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED && i<50){
        delay(200);
        Serial.print(".");
        i++;
    }
    if(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED){
        Serial.println("");
        Str_Buffer = "Connected to network";
        SendToPrinter(0,"aa",0);
        flag_ifWifiConnected = true;
    }
    if(i == 50){
        Serial.println("");
        Str_Buffer = "Error connecting to network";
        SendToPrinter(0,"aa",0);
        flag_ifWifiConnected = false;
    }
.
.
.
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. I already saw this code/methode to store SSID/Passphrase on the internet. But this does not solve my problem with the Mac address cause you only use SSID and passphrase. Also I think writing byte by byte with EEPROM.write is a bit tedious. I think it's simpler and cleaner when using a strict like in my code. But that's up to you.